# Need Help - Getting Bad Request status = 400 in Rest API Integration

Tags: rest-api, apexrest

When I pass hardcode parameter in setbody so it gives me correct response.

```
req.setBody('{"boothId": "100170","coId": "3","operatorId": "3","eventId": "1","salesPersonEmail": "abc@sfdc.com"}');
```

And when i tried to do with dynamic parameters its giving me bad request - status 400.

```
for(SBQQ__Quote__c qli : lstofQuote){
    ProductWrap pwrap = new ProductWrap();
    pwrap.eventId = qli.SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Campaign.A2Z_Event_Id__c;
    pwrap.boothId = qli.SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Campaign.A2Z_Booth_Id__c;
    pwrap.operatorId = qli.SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Owner.Operator_Id__c;     
    pwrap.oEmail = qli.SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Owner.Email;
    pwrap.companyId = qli.SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Account.A2Z_Company_Id__c ;

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('PUT');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('client_id', clientId);
    req.setHeader('client_secret', clientSecret);
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setBody('(JSON.serialize(pwrap)));
    system.debug('testpwrap11' + JSON.serialize(pwrap));
                     
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPresponse res= http.send(req);
    system.debug('res.getBody()'+ res.getBody());
    if (res.getStatusCode() == 202 ) {                                                         
        System.debug('Body 111' + res.getBody());
        System.debug('Body ' + res.getstatuscode());                        
        listofnewQLI.add(oQuoteLine);                                     
    }
}
```

Any suggestion what i did wrong?

Comment: You have a stray `'` in your code. Can you please check your code and verify if you've used `'` or not: `req.setBody('(JSON.serialize(pwrap)));`?

Comment: I just removed ' and use this  req.setBody(JSON.serialize(pwrap)); and its works.Thanks @sfdcfox